# how to add host file in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
        202.142.157.220 linux-eadz.abacus-global.com
        202.142.157.219 ac-hana-2.abacus-global.com ac-hana-2
```

i want to add this host file in ubuntu but due to new user i dont know how???? can someone help me ??????

Comment: You also might want to tell your silly IT department to set up DNS correctly instead of having everyone mess with their hosts file.

Comment: yes i told them and they said that they dont have any idea how to run this host file on ubuntu, they asked to me replace the ubuntu os with windows 10 etc, so i had to do this to run the program :( i will miss ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

The `hosts` file is `/etc/hosts`.

It's better if you add the records you want to the existing file, rather than replace the file (or at least take a backup of it).